# Effectively Splicing a List of Arguments into a Function Call

Tags: common-lisp, sequence

Some of the Common Lisp list and sequence functions can take multiple lists or sequences as their final arguments. For example:

```
(mapcar #'list '(a b) '(c d) '(e f)) => ((a c e) (b d f))
```

But if the final arguments are already consolidated into a list/sequence like `((a b) (c d) (e f) ...)`, how can you achieve the same result (as if the list/sequence were spliced into the original function)? Is there a more straightforward approach than writing a macro?

EDIT: I think I've found one way: `(apply #'funcall #'mapcar #'list '((a b) (c d) (e f)))` but there may be others.

Comment: That `#'funcall` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `apply`, which takes as last argument a *spreadable arguments list designator*.

For your example:

```
(apply #'mapcar #'list '((a b) (c d) (e f)))
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33553757/1281433) (disclaimer, I wrote it) has some more examples of spreadable arglists.